# Trip to Turkey + stops in Paris and Amsterdam

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, turkey, paris, amsterdam

Suppose 4 US passport holders are going to Turkey, and have a booked, insured, round trip from US to Turkey (and back). The flights stop in Paris for ~12 hours during the day on the way to Turkey, and Amsterdam overnight for ~21 hours on the way back.

What process and fees would these people have to go through, in detail, to exit the Paris and Amsterdam airports as tourists during their respective layover periods to sightsee (and book a hotel in Amsterdam overnight)?

Additionally, what are the current steps to entering and staying in Turkey for tourists? Can I get an e-visa and handle it before I get there?

I'm sure some version of these questions have been asked before, but double checking in case there are new restrictions due to Covid.

What authoritative government source would one email/call to get a response regarding these questions in a timely manner (to double check any answers I get here)?

Comment: Are the flights booked as a single ticket (one PNR)? Input the full details into the IATA website https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ for a definitive answer on entry requirements Your time in Paris would be almost halved if you allow for immigration and luggage pickup/checkin. When are you travelling and where / what would you want to visit?

Comment: Also see https://www.schiphol.nl/en/my-travel-day/today and https://www.businessinsider.com/european-airports-with-the-most-delays-2022-7

Comment: The stop in Paris is 8am-11pm Aug 21
Amsterdam 8pm sep1-4pm sep2
These times are when flights arrive/depart
There are no checked bags. Only carry on luggage @Traveller

Comment: Which airport in Paris? You’re asking multiple questions, it would probably be better to split it

Comment: Charles De gaulle, yes one PNR

Comment: I think that all the Amsterdam parts of your question are answered at https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62223/6hour-layover-in-amsterdam or https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144133/long-layover-in-amsterdam-airport and I don't see anything in them that has changed due to COVID. What has changed is that security is currently a nightmare at Schiphol, so you might want to get back between 3 and 4 hours before your flight. Having said that, things might have improved by September as the school holidays will be over. Also look at https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Schiphol_Airport

Answer (score 1):

> What process and fees would these people have to go through, in detail, to exit the Paris and Amsterdam airports as tourists during their respective layover periods to sightsee (and book a hotel in Amsterdam overnight)?

As US passport holders, and until the European response to the ESTA is in place, you don’t have to pay any fees to enter the Schengen area. As of August 1st, 2022, all Covid restrictions have been lifted so you won’t have to pay for a test just to be able to leave the airport. The process is therefore: present yourself to the border control (Schengen entry check by the French police), walk through the luggage claim hall and walk out through one-way doors.

With no luggage, the only thing left is transportation: A taxi to the centre will cost €50-60 (price is fixed but depends on where in the centre you are going, left or right bank of the Seine river). A RER (commuter train) or bus ticket will cost €12 (but that’s per person).

You won’t have a whole lot of time in Paris and need to budget some time to make your way back to the airport and go through security but 12 hours is enough to go to the centre, see a few things or grab lunch. We probably have other questions about that.

Comment: While not mentioned in this answer, the situation in Amsterdam is basically the same, no restrictions for US citizens, good public transport and taxis that may work out more expensive. But do check how early you need to head for the airport, in either case, as staffing problems have been seen all over Europe.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the replies. So, to recap, at CDG and at AMS, no exit fees, no visas, no permits, no covid tests, no vaccine passport checks, nothing? Same for entry, should have no issue?
What do I do on my way back into the airport?

Comment: @Relaxed do I need a Shengen visa?

Comment: @johnrabbit no.